# How to add value to column in which there is already some value

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to add value to column in which there is already some value. So that the value in this console will have  maximum 10 lengths.

On start the value in the column have different lengths

Example. I have DB with 2 columns.
Each value in the ID column should have max 10 characters, if they are to be omitted, they should be preceded by zeros

```
USER    ID
1111    0000012345
2222    001234
3333    567890
4444    67890
5555    7778889
```

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: please read: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `lpad()`:

```
update t
    set id = lpad(id, 10, '0');
```

Or you might want this in a `select`:

```
select t.*, lpad(id, 10, '0') as id_10
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

As per what I understand is, if you want to select ID column which should display length of 10 then below the query.

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICAE('0',10) + ID ,10) FROM <YourTableName>
```

Comment: there is no `replicate()` function in Postgres and the `+` operator is only used to add numbers in SQL, you can't use it with strings.

Comment: Then it would be SELECT LPAD(ID::TEXT, 10, '0') AS ID FROM <TableName>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like below.

```
create temp table my_table(
USER1 int,
ID varchar(10));

insert into my_table
values(1111,'0000012345'),
      (2222, '001234'),
      (3333,'567890'),
      (4444,'67890'),
      (5555,'7778889');

select USER1, 
CASE 
    WHEN length(ID)<10 THEN CONCAT(repeat('0',10-length(ID)),ID)
    ELSE ID
END as ID
from my_table
```

Result will be like this.

```
USER1   ID
1111    0000012345
2222    0000999932
3333    0000333413
2222    0000994554
```

Also in my table I already put constraint that the ID column should be length 10 but if you have values with more than length 10 then I am not sure how you will want to go with that problem as there are different options for that. You can make the whole column "invalid" or truncate it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Updated for Postgres!